# Search data based on two columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a database table like this:

```
Id          Tipo        Provincia
RTOR-0246   INVENTARIO  MADRID
RTOR-0246   SUSTRATO    MADRID
RTOR-0247   INVENTARIO  MADRID
RTOR-0252   INVENTARIO  MADRID
RTOR-0255   SUSTRATO    MADRID
RTOR-0261   SUSTRATO    MADRID
```

I need search from Id the Id's that not have Tipo = Inventario and Create a new line with that data, I mean for example, RTOR-00261 and RTOR-0255 dont have INVENTARIO, I need to create new with the fields that there is in SUSTRATO. All data are in the same table

Final outptut like this:

```
Id          Tipo        Provincia
RTOR-0246   INVENTARIO  MADRID
RTOR-0246   SUSTRATO    MADRID
RTOR-0247   INVENTARIO  MADRID
RTOR-0252   INVENTARIO  MADRID
RTOR-0255   SUSTRATO    MADRID
RTOR-0261   SUSTRATO    MADRID
RTOR-0255   INVENTARIO  MADRID
RTOR-0261   INVENTARIO  MADRID
```

I tried with:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM my_table 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM my_table WHERE id != id)
```

Doesn't work

Other:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM my_table as t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Administrativo FROM my_table where Tipo='INVENTARIO') as sq
where T t1.Tipo='SUSTRATO' and t1.Id=sq.Id
```

Doesn't work as well.

I need help with this - any ideas?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two solutions work (you were very close):

With a Subquery:

```
SELECT `Id` 
FROM `my_table`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `my_table` AS `sub` WHERE `sub`.`Id` = `my_table`.`Id` AND `sub`.`Tipo` = 'INVENTARIO');
```

With a left join:

```
SELECT `my_table`.`Id` 
FROM `my_table` LEFT JOIN
`my_table` AS `Inventario` ON (`Inventario`.`Id` = `my_table`.`Id` AND `Inventario`.`Tipo` = 'INVENTARIO')
WHERE `Inventario`.`Id` IS NULL;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYTYPnquUzxJ6MZbsDjArw/0)

**Edit**: I also think the question should be different. More like "How to select rows that don't match criteria in the same table" or so. The question 'search data based on two columns' is way too broad, that could be answered with 'WHERE ... AND ... '.

Answer (score 0):

You need UNION ALL for the 2 cases and NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT Id, Tipo, Provincia 
FROM my_table 
UNION ALL
SELECT m.Id, 'INVENTARIO', m.Provincia
FROM my_table m
WHERE Tipo = 'SUSTRATO'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM my_table 
  WHERE id = m.id AND Tipo = 'INVENTARIO'
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qA8FWAJ8xgErMDpEFUGcd8/1).
Results:

```
| Id        | Tipo       | Provincia |
| --------- | ---------- | --------- |
| RTOR-0246 | INVENTARIO | MADRID    |
| RTOR-0246 | SUSTRATO   | MADRID    |
| RTOR-0247 | INVENTARIO | MADRID    |
| RTOR-0252 | INVENTARIO | MADRID    |
| RTOR-0255 | SUSTRATO   | MADRID    |
| RTOR-0261 | SUSTRATO   | MADRID    |
| RTOR-0255 | INVENTARIO | MADRID    |
| RTOR-0261 | INVENTARIO | MADRID    |
```

Comment: Thanks...but doesn't work, I have this issue Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns; I've around 20 columns, I putted only 3 for the example. How can I resolve? Why you put m. before the column, but not in colunm Tipo??

Comment: You say in your question that you want to add rows with Tipo = Inventario as is your Final outptut like this: right? But you accepted an answer that returns only ids. If you wanted only the column Id you should have clarified that. If you wanted only 3 columns instead of `select * ...` you could do: `select Id, Tipo, Provincia ....` And m is the alias of the table inside the subquery.